# JSF and Tomcat - Cant deploy

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf

When trying to deploy my JSF project i'm receiving the following error:

`SEVERE: Servlet [Faces Servlet] in web application [/projetojsf] threw load() exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1437)  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1245)  at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:490)   at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:472)    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:865)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:805)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4633)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4926)    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318)  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846)   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318)  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:241)   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:919)   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)`

I've already tried to manually put the .jar files into the lib folder, but when I do it, I receive another error:

Server Tomcat v10.1 Server at localhost failed to start.

Can someone please help me?

I'm expecting to deploy the tomcat project so I can work with JSF

Comment: I moved the .jar files to the folder lib and downgradaded the tomcat 9.0 version. Now its all working. Thanks !!